# Title of UIAlertView is carried on to a UITextField on a different screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview, viewdidload

Is it possible to make the title of a `UIAlertView` get transfered into a UITextField that is in another view when the `clickedButtonAtIndex` button leads to that view?

So, a `UITableViewCell` opens the alertview when clicked, and the alertview has two buttons: `Close` and `Next Screen`. When Next Screen is pushed, another view opens, and in that view should be a `UITextField` that already has the title of the `UIAlertView` in it after the view loads (in viewDidLoad). Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply ask the alert view for its `title`, and pass that to the next view controller.  In the next view controller's `viewDidLoad`, it can put the title in the text field.

```
// In the view controller responsible for the alert view:

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NextViewController *vc = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
    vc.titleForTextField = alertView.title;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// In NextViewController:
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField.text = self.titleForTextField;
}
```

(You'll need to give `NextViewController` a `titleForTextField` property.)

Comment: What will the property look like? 
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *titleForTextField;
?
or NSString ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The property has to be set to NSString * titleForTextField